# correct the url context

Tags: 7, uri

When using $link = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; in page.tpl.php the result of print is:
`f1=All&f2%5Bvalue%5D%5Byear%5D=2009&f2%5Bvalue%5D%5Bmonth%5D=1`
Is there a way to correct the url to print as:
`f1=All&f2[value][year]=2009&f2[value][month]=1` 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to decode the string with [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php):

```
$query_string = urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```